# PowerShell to determine where a specific column has been used

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, column

I am trying to come up with a script to find out in which document libraries under the site collection, a specific column (Company name) has been used.

I am using SharePoint online.

Is this something we can achieve with PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote script in CSOM PowerShell. You will need SharePoint Client DLLs to run it. Please update first 5 lines with appropriate details and update your DLL paths.

You will get CSV as an output.

```
$Username = "<username>";
$Password = "<password>";
$CSVOutputPath = "C:\data.csv";
$SiteCollectionUrl = "<site-collection-url>";
$FieldName = "<Column-Title>"; #Pass the column title that you want to check.
    
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
    
#Array to Skip System Lists and Libraries
$SystemLists = @("Converted Forms", "Master Page Gallery", "Customized Reports", "Form Templates", "List Template Gallery", "Theme Gallery", "Reporting Templates", "Solution Gallery", "Style Library", "Web Part Gallery", "Site Assets", "wfpub", "MicroFeed", "Site Pages");
    
Function CheckIfColumnExist() {
    param($WebUrl = $(throw "Please Enter the Site URL"))
    
    Try {
        Write-Host "Processing Web: "$WebUrl -f Green
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebUrl)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    
        #Get the Web
        $Web = $Ctx.Web
        $Ctx.Load($Ctx.Web)
        $Ctx.Load($Ctx.Web.Webs)
        $Ctx.Load($Ctx.Web.Lists)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    
        #Get all lists
        $Lists = $Ctx.Web.Lists | Where-Object { $_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Hidden -eq $False -and ($SystemLists -notcontains $_.Title) }
     
        Foreach ($List in $Lists) {
            Try {
                $Ctx.Load($List)
                $Ctx.Load($List.Fields)
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    
                $Field = $List.Fields | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq $FieldName }
                if ($Field) { 
                    "$($WebUrl)`t $($List.Title)" | Out-File $CSVOutputPath -Append
                    Write-Host $Field.Title" exist." -f Green 
                } 
            }
            Catch {
                Write-Host -f Red "List Iteration Error: " $_.Exception.Message
            }
        }
    
        #Loop through each each subsite in site
        Foreach ($Subweb in $Web.Webs) {
            CheckIfColumnExist $Subweb.Url
        }
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host -f Red "Error: " $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
    
Try {
    #Get Credentials to Connect
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
            
    #Write the CSV Header - Tab Separated
    "WebUrl`t Document Library" | Out-file $CSVOutputPath
    
    Write-Host "Processing Site: "$SiteCollectionUrl -f DarkYellow
    CheckIfColumnExist $SiteCollectionUrl
       
    Write-Host "Report is ready at location: " $CSVOutputPath -f Green
}
Catch {
    Write-Host -f Red "Error!: " $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from powershell:

```
$site_url = 'https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/site_collection'
$lib = 'Shared Documents'
Connect-PnPOnline  -Url $site_url -Interactive
$site_column = Get-PnPField -List $lib -Identity "Company Name"
```

SharePoint is very particular with spaces, so you might have to escape the space.  In SharePoint this looks like: 'Company_x0020_Name'

You can extend this to read a list of site collections and libraries to scan them all.